# memory leak in Sharepoint using Console app

Tags: c#, sharepoint, memory-leaks

I have console app that uses OpenWeb(myWeb) without closing and without "using". In the WebPart it leads to memory leak. But, as I understand, after .exe file closing, garbage collector clean memory, is't it? Or does OpenWeb() creates all objects in w3w pool anywhere I use it?

Comment: *Why* aren't you making use of `using`?

Comment: cause applications, that running on the servers, wrote another person, not by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When process exits, OS releases all resources, used by this process. So, to be more accurate, resources may be released not because of GC work.

If your application creates one `IDisposable`, uses it, and then exits, resources, used by `IDisposable` will be disposed. But, usually applications are more complex. So, I'd recommend to use `using` or `try/finally` even in small applications. At least, you won't forget to call `Dispose` somewhere later.